# Why do the two types of usage of nn.LSTM get different results?

Tags: pytorch, lstm

In the code, 12 is the seq_len; 20 is the muti-prediction;7 is the numbers;32 is the hidden_size.I use two ways to use lstm, one is simply considering 20*7 as batch dimension, and the other is use "for loop" in python to generate results one-by-one in dimension N(N=7).
Here is the code:

```
import torch as t
lstm = t.nn.LSTM(input_size=64,
        hidden_size=64,
        num_layers=1,
        bias=True,
        batch_first=False,
        dropout=0,
        bidirectional=False)

a = t.randn(12, 20, 7, 64) # 12 is the seq_len; 20 is the muti-prediction;7 is the numbers;32 is the hidden_size
hn = t.randn(1, 20, 7, 64)
cn = t.randn(1, 20, 7, 64)

out1, _ = lstm(a.reshape(12, 20 * 7, 64), (hn.reshape(1, 20 * 7, 64), cn.reshape(1, 20 * 7, 64)))
out1 = out1.reshape(12, 20, 7, 64)

out2 = []
for n in range(7):
    out_tmp, _ = lstm(a[:, :, n], (hn[:, :, n], cn[:, :, n]))
    out2.append(out_tmp)
out2 = t.stack(out2, dim=2)


print(out1 == out2) # why out1 is not equal to out2
```

[There are many Fasles in the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcDIl.png)

Comment: Have you tried using [torch.allclose](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.allclose.html) to compare the two outputs?

Comment: Yes, the output is "False".

Comment: The outputs are equal for me. I'm using Python 3.10.8 and torch 1.13.1.